# Cannot Install My Weather Indicator In Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, dependencies, weather

good day,

i'm having an issue getting my weather indicator to install on kubuntu 19.04 disco dingo. i keep getting the following. any help and or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks

```
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
my-weather-indicator : Depends: gir1.2-webkit-3.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/75567-Cannot-Install-My-Weather-Indicator

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/weather-indicator-desktop-widget-ubuntu-16-04/

https://github.com/atareao/my-weather-indicator/issues/58

Comment: **1**:I don't see "my-weather-indicator" in 19.04 repos. **2**: Something made for one desktop environment may not work in another. **3**: Your kubuntuforums.net link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DKBose The app is provided by a PPA - PPA:atareao/atareao - that says 19.04 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gir1.2-webkit-3.0 is [unavailable](https://pkgs.org/download/gir1.2-webkit-3.0) for Ubuntu 19.04.

However, you can :

- Try and side-load this dependency from [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/gir1.2-webkit2-4.0_2.24.1-1_amd64.deb.html) however keep in mind that this might have some other missing dependencies.. so your mileage may vary. If that is the case you can track down those packages as well.. careful as you can enter dependency hell in short order.
- Try and install [`gir1.2-webkit2-4.0`](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/gir1.2-webkit2-4.0_2.24.1-1_amd64.deb.html) from the Ubuntu Multiverse, installing `my-weather-indicator` with the following flag `--no-install-recommends`, again YMMV.

The best option is what was suggested on [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=6006717#post6006717): Installing/Building the app yourself. They have a `setup.py` on their [GitHub](https://github.com/atareao/my-weather-indicator).

The package from this PPA is broken for sure as some of the packages it calls for will be missing from Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this software, the `girl 1.2.-webkit` did not install.

But if you surf to:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/atareao_atareao/bionic/main/base/my-weather-indicator

and you choose all arch deb package, and open this with the normal sofware install procedure, it will install and work.